# why does window object in javascript doesnt has this key but also console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var varFunc = function declareFunc() {
  console.log(this); // window
  console.log(this.declareFunc); // undefined
  console.log(declareFunc); // function body
}
console.log(this) // window
varFunc();
```

i know `this` in `function` direction to  `window`, but `window` doesn't has props `declareFunc`, but , finally this code still console `[Function: declareFunc]`  why?

and if i use [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) :

```
var varFunc = function declareFunc() {
  console.log(this); // window
  console.log(declareFunc.name) // "declareFunc"
  console.log(varFunc.name); // "declareFunc". but why?
  console.log(this.declareFunc); // undefined
  console.log(declareFunc); // function body
}
console.log(varFunc.name) // "declareFunc". why?
var aa = function (){}
console.log(aa.name) // "aa"
console.log(this) // window
varFunc();
```

Comment: I don't understand anything to your title or your question, but all I can say is that `var varFunc = function declareFunc() { }` is wrong. You want to use either `var varFunc = function() { }` or `function declareFunc() { }`, not a mix.

Comment: @JeremyThille This is what you basically do when using `require`, for example

Comment: The issue is the scoping of a **named function expression**. Google for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var varFunc = function declareFunc() {
  console.log(varFunc===declareFunc);//true
}
```

This function has now two names: *varFunc* externally and *declareFunc* internally, so inside of it, you can access *declareFunc,varFunc and window.varFunc* , and outside:

```
console.log(varFunc,declareFunc);//function, undefined/error
```

Comment: inside of it, `window.varFunc` is a function when I run in browser but `window` is undefined in node.

Comment: @borkes replace *window* with *global*. Principle is the same